# Moderncv - errors on sty and tex files

Tags: errors, moderncv

I have successfully used the `moderncv` package for several years. A few months ago, the following errors appeared out of the blue :

```
Command \mobilesymbol undefined. \renewcommand*{\mobilesymbol}
Command \phonesymbol undefined. \renewcommand*{\phonesymbol}
Command \faxsymbol undefined. \renewcommand*{\faxsymbol}
Undefined control sequence. \firstname
Missing \begin{document}. \firstname{F
Undefined control sequence. \familyname
Undefined control sequence. \begin{document}
Undefined control sequence. \begin{document}
Undefined control sequence. \begin{document}
Undefined control sequence. \begin{document}
Undefined control sequence. \begin{document}
Undefined control sequence. \begin{document}
Undefined control sequence. \begin{document}
Undefined control sequence. \begin{document}
Undefined control sequence. \makelettertitle
Undefined control sequence. \makelettertitle
Undefined control sequence. \makelettertitle
Undefined control sequence. \makecvtitle
Package graphics Error: Division by 0. \makecvtitle
Undefined control sequence. \makecvtitle
Undefined control sequence. \makecvtitle
```

Here is a MWE :

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 

\moderncvstyle{classic} 

\moderncvcolor{blue} 

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} 

\usepackage{graphicx} 

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{lmodern} 

\renewcommand*{\namefont}{\fontsize{20}{0}\mdseries\upshape} 


\firstname{Firstname} 
\familyname{Lastname}
\title{Profession}
\phone{+33 (0)x xx xx xx xx}
\email{email@gmail.com}
\photo[70pt][0.4pt]{pictures/file.jpg} 

\begin{document}

\clearpage
\recipient{Recipient}{}
\date{\today}
\opening{Madame, Monsieur,} 
\closing{} 

\makelettertitle     

Blabla...

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{2017--2019}{Master Degree}{University X}{Country X}{}{}

\section{Professional experience}
\cventry{2018}{Job X}{Company X}{Country X}{}{}

\end{document}
```

Removing the `fontspec` package from the preamble, here is the log file, although not in its entirety because too long :

```
    This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (TeX Live 2019/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=xelatex 2019.7.4)  4 JUL 2019 15:51
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**CV-LM.tex
(./CV-LM.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
(./moderncv.cls
Document Class: moderncv 2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter d
ocument class
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo
File: size11.clo 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2018/08/19 v2.5f e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count80
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: xetex.def on input line 225.

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/xetex.def
File: xetex.def 2017/06/24 v5.0h Graphics/color driver for xetex
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/colortbl/colortbl.sty
Package: colortbl 2018/12/12 v1.0d Color table columns (DPC)

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty
Package: array 2018/12/30 v2.4k Tabular extension package (FMi)
\col@sep=\dimen102
\ar@mcellbox=\box27
\extrarowheight=\dimen103
\NC@list=\toks14
\extratabsurround=\skip41
\backup@length=\skip42
\ar@cellbox=\box28
)
\everycr=\toks15
\minrowclearance=\skip43
)
\rownum=\count81
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1348.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1364.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1367.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2018/08/11 v2.0j Standard LaTeX package

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def
File: t1enc.def 2018/08/11 v2.0j Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding T1 on input line 48.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+lmr on input line 105.

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/t1lmr.fd
File: t1lmr.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/lmodern.sty
Package: lmodern 2009/10/30 v1.6 Latin Modern Fonts
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/lmr/m/n on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/m/it --> OML/lmm/m/it on input line 23.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/m/n --> OMS/lmsy/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/lmex/m/n on input line 25.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/b/it --> OML/lmm/b/it on input line 27.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/b/n --> OMS/lmsy/b/n on input line 28.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/lmex/m/n on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> OT1/lmss/m/n on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> OT1/lmr/m/it on input line 33.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/lmtt/m/n on input line 34.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> OT1/lmss/bx/n on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> OT1/lmr/bx/it on input line 37.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/lmtt/m/n on input line 38.
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip10
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks16
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: xetex.def on input line 99.
)
\Gin@req@height=\dimen104
\Gin@req@width=\dimen105
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.sty
Package: fancyhdr 2019/01/31 v3.10 Extensive control of page headers and footer
s
\f@nch@headwidth=\skip44
\f@nch@O@elh=\skip45
\f@nch@O@erh=\skip46
\f@nch@O@olh=\skip47
\f@nch@O@orh=\skip48
\f@nch@O@elf=\skip49
\f@nch@O@erf=\skip50
\f@nch@O@olf=\skip51
\f@nch@O@orf=\skip52
) (./tweaklist.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty
Package: calc 2017/05/25 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
\calc@Acount=\count82
\calc@Bcount=\count83
\calc@Adimen=\dimen106
\calc@Bdimen=\dimen107
\calc@Askip=\skip53
\calc@Bskip=\skip54
LaTeX Info: Redefining \setlength on input line 80.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \addtolength on input line 81.
\calc@Ccount=\count84
\calc@Cskip=\skip55
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2019-04-06 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex
Package: expl3 2019-04-06 L3 programming layer (code)
\c_max_int=\count85
\l_tmpa_int=\count86
\l_tmpb_int=\count87
\g_tmpa_int=\count88
\g_tmpb_int=\count89
\g__kernel_prg_map_int=\count90
\c__ior_term_ior=\count91
\c_log_iow=\count92
\l_iow_line_count_int=\count93
\l__iow_line_target_int=\count94
\l__iow_one_indent_int=\count95
\l__iow_indent_int=\count96
\c_zero_dim=\dimen108
\c_max_dim=\dimen109
\l_tmpa_dim=\dimen110
\l_tmpb_dim=\dimen111
\g_tmpa_dim=\dimen112
\g_tmpb_dim=\dimen113
\c_zero_skip=\skip56
\c_max_skip=\skip57
\l_tmpa_skip=\skip58
\l_tmpb_skip=\skip59
\g_tmpa_skip=\skip60
\g_tmpb_skip=\skip61
\c_zero_muskip=\muskip11
\c_max_muskip=\muskip12
\l_tmpa_muskip=\muskip13
\l_tmpb_muskip=\muskip14
\g_tmpa_muskip=\muskip15
\g_tmpb_muskip=\muskip16
\l_keys_choice_int=\count97
\l__intarray_loop_int=\count98
\c__intarray_sp_dim=\dimen114
\g__intarray_font_int=\count99
\c__fp_leading_shift_int=\count100
\c__fp_middle_shift_int=\count101
\c__fp_trailing_shift_int=\count102
\c__fp_big_leading_shift_int=\count103
\c__fp_big_middle_shift_int=\count104
\c__fp_big_trailing_shift_int=\count105
\c__fp_Bigg_leading_shift_int=\count106
\c__fp_Bigg_middle_shift_int=\count107
\c__fp_Bigg_trailing_shift_int=\count108
\g__fp_array_int=\count109
\l__fp_array_loop_int=\count110
\l__sort_length_int=\count111
\l__sort_min_int=\count112
\l__sort_top_int=\count113
\l__sort_max_int=\count114
\l__sort_true_max_int=\count115
\l__sort_block_int=\count116
\l__sort_begin_int=\count117
\l__sort_end_int=\count118
\l__sort_A_int=\count119
\l__sort_B_int=\count120
\l__sort_C_int=\count121
\l__tl_analysis_normal_int=\count122
\l__tl_analysis_index_int=\count123
\l__tl_analysis_nesting_int=\count124
\l__tl_analysis_type_int=\count125
\l__regex_internal_a_int=\count126
\l__regex_internal_b_int=\count127
\l__regex_internal_c_int=\count128
\l__regex_balance_int=\count129
\l__regex_group_level_int=\count130
\l__regex_mode_int=\count131
\c__regex_cs_in_class_mode_int=\count132
\c__regex_cs_mode_int=\count133
\l__regex_catcodes_int=\count134
\l__regex_default_catcodes_int=\count135
\c__regex_catcode_L_int=\count136
\c__regex_catcode_O_int=\count137
\c__regex_catcode_A_int=\count138
\c__regex_all_catcodes_int=\count139
\l__regex_show_lines_int=\count140
\l__regex_min_state_int=\count141
\l__regex_max_state_int=\count142
\l__regex_left_state_int=\count143
\l__regex_right_state_int=\count144
\l__regex_capturing_group_int=\count145
\l__regex_min_pos_int=\count146
\l__regex_max_pos_int=\count147
\l__regex_curr_pos_int=\count148
\l__regex_start_pos_int=\count149
\l__regex_success_pos_int=\count150
\l__regex_curr_char_int=\count151
\l__regex_curr_catcode_int=\count152
\l__regex_last_char_int=\count153
\l__regex_case_changed_char_int=\count154
\l__regex_curr_state_int=\count155
\l__regex_step_int=\count156
\l__regex_min_active_int=\count157
\l__regex_max_active_int=\count158
\l__regex_replacement_csnames_int=\count159
\l__regex_match_count_int=\count160
\l__regex_min_submatch_int=\count161
\l__regex_submatch_int=\count162
\l__regex_zeroth_submatch_int=\count163
\g__regex_trace_regex_int=\count164
\c_empty_box=\box29
\l_tmpa_box=\box30
\l_tmpb_box=\box31
\g_tmpa_box=\box32
\g_tmpb_box=\box33
\l__box_top_dim=\dimen115
\l__box_bottom_dim=\dimen116
\l__box_left_dim=\dimen117
\l__box_right_dim=\dimen118
\l__box_top_new_dim=\dimen119
\l__box_bottom_new_dim=\dimen120
\l__box_left_new_dim=\dimen121
\l__box_right_new_dim=\dimen122
\l__box_internal_box=\box34
\l__coffin_internal_box=\box35
\l__coffin_internal_dim=\dimen123
\l__coffin_offset_x_dim=\dimen124
\l__coffin_offset_y_dim=\dimen125
\l__coffin_x_dim=\dimen126
\l__coffin_y_dim=\dimen127
\l__coffin_x_prime_dim=\dimen128
\l__coffin_y_prime_dim=\dimen129
\c_empty_coffin=\box36
\l__coffin_aligned_coffin=\box37
\l__coffin_aligned_internal_coffin=\box38
\l_tmpa_coffin=\box39
\l_tmpb_coffin=\box40
\g_tmpa_coffin=\box41
\g_tmpb_coffin=\box42
\l__coffin_bounding_shift_dim=\dimen130
\l__coffin_left_corner_dim=\dimen131
\l__coffin_right_corner_dim=\dimen132
\l__coffin_bottom_corner_dim=\dimen133
\l__coffin_top_corner_dim=\dimen134
\l__coffin_scaled_total_height_dim=\dimen135
\l__coffin_scaled_width_dim=\dimen136
\c__coffin_empty_coffin=\box43
\l__coffin_display_coffin=\box44
\l__coffin_display_coord_coffin=\box45
\l__coffin_display_pole_coffin=\box46
\l__coffin_display_offset_dim=\dimen137
\l__coffin_display_x_dim=\dimen138
\l__coffin_display_y_dim=\dimen139
\g__file_internal_ior=\read1
\l__seq_internal_a_int=\count165
\l__seq_internal_b_int=\count166
\c__deprecation_minus_one=\count167
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3xdvipdfmx.def
File: l3xdvipdfmx.def 2019-04-06 v L3 Experimental driver: xdvipdfmx
\g__driver_image_int=\count168
\g__driver_pdf_object_int=\count169
))
Package: xparse 2019-03-05 L3 Experimental document command parser
\l__xparse_current_arg_int=\count170
\g__xparse_grabber_int=\count171
\l__xparse_m_args_int=\count172
\l__xparse_v_nesting_int=\count173
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.sty
Package: microtype 2019/02/28 v2.7b Micro-typographical refinements (RS)
\MT@toks=\toks17
\MT@count=\count174
LaTeX Info: Redefining \textls on input line 790.
\MT@outer@kern=\dimen140
LaTeX Info: Redefining \textmicrotypecontext on input line 1336.
\MT@listname@count=\count175

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype-xetex.def
File: microtype-xetex.def 2019/02/28 v2.7b Definitions specific to xetex (RS)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \lsstyle on input line 258.
)
Package microtype Info: Loading configuration file microtype.cfg.

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.cfg
File: microtype.cfg 2019/02/28 v2.7b microtype main configuration file (RS)
))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/moderncv/moderncvcollection.sty
Package: moderncvcollection 2015/07/28 v2.0.0 moderncv collections
\c@collection@iterator=\count176
)
(./moderncvcompatibility.sty
Package: moderncvcompatibility 2012/10/31 v1.2.0 modern curriculum vitae and le
tter compatibility patches
)
\c@collection@phones@count=\count177
\c@collection@socials@count=\count178
\c@cvcolumnscounter=\count179
\c@cvcolumnsautowidthcounter=\count180
\c@tmpiteratorcounter=\count181
\cvcolumnsdummywidth=\skip62
\cvcolumnswidth=\skip63
\cvcolumnsautowidth=\skip64
\cvcolumnautowidth=\skip65
\bibindent=\skip66
) (./moderncvstyleclassic.sty
Package: moderncvstyleclassic 2012/10/31 v1.2.0 modern curriculum vitae and let
ter style scheme: classic


! LaTeX Error: Command \mobilesymbol undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.41 \renewcommand*{\mobilesymbol}
                                  {\marvosymbol{72}~}
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.


! LaTeX Error: Command \phonesymbol undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.42 \renewcommand*{\phonesymbol}
                                 {\marvosymbol{84}~}
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.


! LaTeX Error: Command \faxsymbol undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.43 \renewcommand*{\faxsymbol}
                               {\marvosymbol{117}~}
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

\quotewidth=\skip67
\hintscolumnwidth=\skip68
\separatorcolumnwidth=\skip69
\maincolumnwidth=\skip70
\doubleitemmaincolumnwidth=\skip71
\listitemsymbolwidth=\skip72
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OMS+lmr on input line 78.
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/omslmr.fd
File: omslmr.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OMS+lmsy on input line 78.


(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/omslmsy.fd
File: omslmsy.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OMS/lmr/m/n' in size <12> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OMS/lmsy/m/n' tried instead on input line 78.
\listitemmaincolumnwidth=\skip73
\listdoubleitemmaincolumnwidth=\skip74
\makecvtitlenamewidth=\skip75
\baseletterheight=\skip76
\cvitemwithcommentmainbox=\box47
\cvitemwithcommentmainlength=\skip77
\cvitemwithcommentcommentlength=\skip78
) (./moderncvcolorblue.sty
Package: moderncvcolorblue 2012/10/31 v1.2.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter
 color scheme: blue
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
Package: geometry 2018/04/16 v5.8 Page Geometry

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2018/09/07 v3.3 Provides the ifpdf switch
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty
Package: ifvtex 2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
Package ifvtex Info: VTeX not detected.
)
\Gm@cnth=\count182
\Gm@cntv=\count183
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count184
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen141
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen142
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen143
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen144
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen145
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen146
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen147
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen148
\Gm@dimlist=\toks18
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/float/float.sty
Package: float 2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
\c@float@type=\count185
\float@exts=\toks19
\float@box=\box48
\@float@everytoks=\toks20
\@floatcapt=\box49
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
Package: babel 2019/04/03 3.29 The Babel package

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/switch.def
File: switch.def 2019/04/03 3.29 Babel switching mechanism
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-french/french.ldf
Language: french 2019/03/30 v3.5e French support from the babel system

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def
File: babel.def 2019/04/03 3.29 Babel common definitions
\babel@savecnt=\count186
\U@D=\dimen149

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/xebabel.def
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/txtbabel.def))
\bbl@dirlevel=\count187
)
\l@acadian = a dialect from \language\l@french 
\FB@nonchar=\count188
Package french.ldf Info: No need for active punctuation characters
(french.ldf)             with this version of XeTeX!
(french.ldf)             reported on input line 326.
\FB@punctthick=\XeTeXcharclass1
\FB@punctthin=\XeTeXcharclass2
\FB@punctnul=\XeTeXcharclass3
\FB@guilo=\XeTeXcharclass4
\FB@guilf=\XeTeXcharclass5
\FB@guilnul=\XeTeXcharclass6
\FBguill@level=\count189
\FBold@everypar=\toks21
\FB@Mht=\dimen150
LaTeX Info: Redefining \degres on input line 777.
\mc@charclass=\count190
\mc@charfam=\count191
\mc@charslot=\count192
\std@mcc=\count193
\dec@mcc=\count194
\c@FBcaption@count=\count195
\listindentFB=\dimen151
\descindentFB=\dimen152
\labelindentFB=\dimen153
\labelwidthFB=\dimen154
\leftmarginFB=\dimen155
\parindentFFN=\dimen156
\FBfnindent=\dimen157
))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/carlisle/scalefnt.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2018/08/11 v2.0j Standard LaTeX package

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def
File: t1enc.def 2018/08/11 v2.0j Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding T1 on input line 48.
))
! Undefined control sequence.
l.24 \firstname
               {Firstname}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.


! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...
```

I have updated TeX Live and my distro (4.14.130-1-MANJARO x86_64), to no avail. I have donwloaded the latest `moderncv.cls` file. The first three errors of the log point to the `moderncvstyleclassic.sty` file, while the rest point to the `.tex` file.

Any help appreciated.

UPDATE : Deleting  `moderncvcompatibility.sty` removed many errors. Repopulating the folder with all files from [moderncv](https://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) resolved the remaining errors in the MWE. Other trouble occurring with the `FontAwesome` package in my "real" CV folder (as opposed to the MWE) was resolved too.

Comment: Don't use fontspec together with fontenc and lmodern. Correct the document, compile again and then show the log-file.

Comment: Hi Ulrike, thanks for your suggestion. Removing fontspec from the packages in the preamble and compiling again does not change anything in the log file. I also tried the other way around, keeping fontspec while removing fontenc+lmodern. This did not change anything either. I compared the logs with [https://text-compare.com/](https://text-compare.com/).

Comment: I didn't say that it would solve the problem, only that it is wrong to use both together. Show the log.

Comment: Original question edited to show the log after removing fontspec.

Comment: @Makishima it is the start of the log file that is the most important, because it shows versions, package locations etc. So please share the log from the top until the first error.

Comment: @Makishima to clarify my previous comment: it looks like you copy the log from your editor (because it is not in English and the messages are formatted in a non-standard order), the real log file contains much more information. Assuming your file is called `yourfile.tex` the log file is called `yourfile.log` (i.e., the `.tex` extension is changed to `.log`), the file is placed in the same folder as your `.tex` file and it can be opened with any text editor.

Comment: @Marijn : Thanks for the explanation. I have updated the original question with the exact contents of the log. It's not complete because of character restriction, however the start of the log is on it.

Comment: You have old moderncv files in the folder of your document, e.g. /moderncvcompatibility.sty. Remove them and try again.

Comment: Please see my added answer ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues in your code:

1. You are using both

   ```
   \usepackage{fontspec}
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
   ```

   which do simply not work together! Use one of them, but not both. I suggest to use the second, you have no special code shown in your mwe that needs to compile with XeLaTeX. So I also suggest to use `pdflatex` to compile the cv ...
2. Your used code

   ```
   \firstname{Firstname} 
   \familyname{Lastname}
   ```

   shows me, that your original code was used in an old version of `moderncv` where command `\name{firstname}{lastname}` was unknown. Consider to change your complete code to use the new commands. That also means to change `\phone` and you will be able to add new informations like your xing contact etc. to your cv ...
3. You are using the current version of `moderncv` as shown in your log file (`moderncv 2015/07/28 v2.0.0`), but

   ```
   (./moderncvcompatibility.sty
   Package: moderncvcompatibility 2012/10/31 v1.2.0 modern curriculum vitae and le
   tter compatibility patches
   )
   ```

   shows you have a **local** version of an outdated version of `moderncvcompatibility 2012/10/31 v1.2.0` in your working directory. Delete it! The same is valid for this part of your log file:

   ```
   (./moderncvstyleclassic.sty
   Package: moderncvstyleclassic 2012/10/31 v1.2.0 modern curriculum vitae and let
   ter style scheme: classic


   ! LaTeX Error: Command \mobilesymbol undefined.
   ```

   It also shows that you have a local outdated version of `moderncvstyleclassic.sty` in your working directory: `moderncvstyleclassic 2012/10/31 v1.2.0`! Delete it and all other local copies of outdated files from version 1.2 of `moderncv`!
   As you can see following in your log file

   ```
    (./moderncvcolorblue.sty
    Package: moderncvcolorblue 2012/10/31 v1.2.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter
    color scheme: blue
    )
   ```

   package `moderncvcolorblue.sty` in your local folder is also outdated ...

With the following mwe (deleted `fontspec`)

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 

\moderncvstyle{classic} 
\moderncvcolor{blue} 

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
%\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{fontspec} % <========================================= ?????

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} 

\renewcommand*{\namefont}{\fontsize{20}{0}\mdseries\upshape} 


\firstname{Firstname} 
\familyname{Lastname}
\title{Profession}
\phone{+33 (0)x xx xx xx xx}
\email{email@gmail.com}
\photo[70pt][0.4pt]{example-image} % <==================================

\begin{document}

\clearpage
\recipient{Recipient}{}
\date{\today}
\opening{Madame, Monsieur,} 
\closing{} 

\makelettertitle     

Blabla...

\clearpage % <==========================================================
\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{2017--2019}{Master Degree}{University X}{Country X}{}{}

\section{Professional experience}
\cventry{2018}{Job X}{Company X}{Country X}{}{}

\end{document}
```

and compiles with `pdflatex` without error messages I get the following two pages (see added `\clearpage` please):

[image: letter]

and

[image: cv]

To summarize the problems here:

1. **Install** only the **current version** of `moderncv` to your system using the commands of your tex distribution (with MiKteX you have to use the MiKTeX Console, and there the `Package` manager, I do not know TeX Live, sorry)
2. **never** install/copy outdated versions of parts of old `moderncv` versions into your local directory. You simply do not need them if you have a proper installation of current `moderncv` on your system.
3. Check the given examples with `moderncv` to see the new defined commands you can use with the current version of `moderncv`.

Comment: Thank you, that was beautifully explained and summarized. Thanks to all the other contributors as well.